# i've tried to create a Java login script but my code doesnt work

Tags: java, swing, authentication, actionlistener

i've been trying to make a login script in java, i've been looking around and i found an error that people said that my script doesnt work because i didn't use Scanners, i now added those but my script still does not work what can be the error?

```
   package random;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import random.*;
    public class core extends Window
    {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Window().Create();

        }






    public void sqlstatement()
    {


    }
    public static void succesfullLogin()
    {
    System.out.println("it worked!");

    }




    }
```

**this is the Window.java file**

```
package random;

import java.awt.ActiveEvent;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Window extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    public void Gridbags(int height,int width)
    {

    }

    public void Create()
    {
           JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(null);
            frame.setSize(600,500);

            frame.setResizable(false);
            JButton login = new JButton("Login");
            JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
            JLabel usernamelbl = new JLabel("username:");
            JLabel passwordlbl = new JLabel("Password:");
            JTextField userinput = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField password = new JTextField(10);
            password.setText("password");
            userinput.setText("root");


            usernamelbl.setBounds(160, 160, 80, 25);
            userinput.setBounds(225, 160, 160, 25);

            passwordlbl.setBounds(160, 190, 80, 25);
            password.setBounds(225, 190, 160, 25);

            login.setBounds(160, 230, 80, 25);




            login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                        boolean active = true;
                        String mysqluser = "root";
                        String mysqlPass = "password";

                        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                        Scanner userscan = new Scanner(userinput.getText());
                //      Scanner passScan = new Scanner(password.getText());
                        if(userscan.equals(mysqluser))
            //          && passScan.equals(mysqlPass))
            {

                                if(active = true) {

                                    core.succesfullLogin();
                                }



                    }
                }
            });


            panel.add(password);
            panel.add(login);
            panel.add(userinput);
            panel.add(usernamelbl);
            panel.add(passwordlbl);
            panel.add(logout);
          frame.add(panel);
      //    frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you get eny error/ exception ? Any output?

Comment: I wonder, what your actual problem is. What doesn't work?

Comment: @AdamKortylewicz i dont get any errors that's why i'am confused it says the code is correct (i am using Eclipse IDE) and when i run it nothing happens

Comment: @Johannes when i type in the username (root) and the password (password) it should say "it worked". but it gives it does not

Answer (score 0):

userscan is of type Scanner. Comparing it with an string will always return false.
Simply comparing the strings worked for me.

```
if(userinput.getText().equals(mysqluser)&& password.getText().equals(mysqlPass))
```

Comment: @ Sven: You don't need that Scanner-object. Check out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm for a short introduction to java.util.Scanner. Also: If Turamarth's answer helped you, you should vote it up (and mark it as the right answer).